# Order a queryset in django by an annotated field and append the rest of the objects that did not fit the criteria

Tags: python, django, web

So this snippet practically explains what I want to do

```
bloc_results = bloc_results.annotate(num_mates=Count(profilebloc__profile__in=probable_mates)).order_by("-num_mates")
```

I know this is not possible but it was the easiest way I found to explain the situation. the variable probable_mates is a list filled with the pk's of a user table. So I have to get that number and order by it. That's no problem using filter. The thing is that using filter only retrieves the objects that match the id's on that probable_mates list, not all of them with the ones with the highest number of matches up at the top which is what I need to get. How can I do that with the Django ORM without going raw SQL? Thanks!

EDIT: I'll clarify a bit by explaining what this is doing: There are a bunch of clubs that will be added to this webapp and I need sorting by two different parameters. One is by the number of members of each club which is pretty easy. The second one if by "Club friends" so that all of the clubs are ordered by the number of common friends they have with the logged in user even if that user hasn't joined that club. Also that is not so hard. The problem is that when I get that queryset and order it it only displays the clubs that have club friends in common, not the rest. I need the ones that have club friends at the top, ordered by number of mutual club friends and the rest at the bottom, even if they don't have club friends in common.

Comment: say it again please? what do you want to get?

Comment: I edited my question with hopefully enough info.

Comment: please publish your relevant models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a pretty badly explained question but I solved it by using the | operator to concatenate both querysets like this:

```
new_queryset = one_queryset | second_queryset
```

Did not have to use lists after all.

Answer (score 0):

Like akonsu said in his comment, I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish. That said, this sounds similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750232/how-to-get-similar-projects-based-on-tags-in-django) I just answered. Adapted to your model names, does the following do what you want?

```
matches = bloc_results.objects.filter(profilebloc__profile__in=probable_mates)
matches = matches.annotate(Count('num_mates'))
results = matches.order_by('-num_mates')
```

If not, I think you need to clarify your question a bit.

Comment: I edited my question with more info. This is very close (In fact it was as far as I got before running into my new problem)

Comment: I've read you additions a couple of time, but still I can't really figure out what you're trying to accomplish. Your story would be a lot cleaner if you would provide some model info so that we can see the relations you are working with. That said, it sounds you want to combine two unrelated querysets together: isn't it an option to combine them by yourself as weighing seems to be desired?

Comment: Yeap. That would be an option. But I can't find a way to do it other than turning everything to a list. The thing is that I already did a few template tags that depend on this data to be a queryset. Not a list. Perhaps I'll have to rewrite them to take lists.

Comment: If you have two querysets, you might join them together using [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). Turning it into a list isn't a problem in itself I'd say, since you would have to do that at some point eventually to use the results. To make this cleaner, you could consider using properties as described by James Bennett in [this blog post](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/aug/18/django-tips-using-properties-models-and-managers/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to approach this from your `profilebloc` model. Count mates using that model, and then filter the results to leave only profile blocs that are in your `bloc_results`. Sorry, without your models I cannot be clearer.