# How to get similar projects based on tags in Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have `Project` and `Tag` models in my application with a many-to-many relationship between them. On each project's page I want to list 3 additional projects that have the most tags in common with it. How can I perform this query?

```
class Tag(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Project(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
  ...
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to pack it all in one line:

```
Project.objects.filter(tags__in=current_project.tags.all()).annotate(Count('name')).order_by('-name__count')[:3]
```

Or, broken down in steps:

```
tags = current_project.tags.all()
matches = Project.objects.filter(tags__in=tags).annotate(Count('name'))
results = matches.order_by('-name__count')[:3]
```

The logic goes as follows:

1. `current_project` is the instance of the project you want the relations for.
2. The `filter` selects all projects that have tags that are the same as the current project.
3. The `annotate` adds a variable to the return values that counts the number of similar names. As projects that match multiple tags are returned multiple times, this value in indicative for the number of matches.
4. The results are sorted on the annotated `name__count` variable. To get the top 3 results, the list is capped using `[:3]`.

Comment: And put this in a attribute on the `Project` class. Replace `current_project` with `self`, ofcourse.

Comment: Thanks!! worked almost perfect. one little important thing to make it work:
`from django.db.models import Count`